# Initializing memory allocator in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying to implement an `init_allocator()` function that initializes the memory allocator and makes a portion of `_length` bytes available. The allocator uses a `_basic_block_size` as its minimal unit of allocation. The function returns the amount of memory made available to the allocator. If an error occurred, it returns `0`.

This is what I have so far:

```
int memAvail;  // amount of memory to be made available to allocator

unsigned int init_allocator(unsigned int _basic_block_size, unsigned int _length){
    if (_basic_block_size < _ length){
        memAvail = _length/_basic_block_size;
        return memAvail;
    }
    else{           
        return 0;
    }   
}
```

I don't know if this is the right implementation but It seems right to me. Is there something I'm doing wrong? Am I supposed to make use of pointers? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Your requirments are unclear, but most memory sub-allocators do a bit more than that.  For instance, you should call your OS API for a large block of memory to manage.

Comment: I'm supposed to implement a trivial memory allocator. I'm not sure what OS AP1 means

Answer (score 2):

This is an example memory allocator from Chapter 5.4 in [Kernighan and Ritchie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language)

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define ALLOCSIZE 10000 

static char allocbuf[ALLOCSIZE]; 
static char *allocp=allocbuf; 

/* Return pointer to n characters */
char *alloc(int n)
{
   if(allocbuf+ALLOCSIZE-allocp>=n){
       // It fits 
       allocp+=n;
       return allocp-n;
   }else 
       // Not enough room
       return 0;
}
```

`allocbuf` is the memory buffer where you store your chars, since this is a char allocator. `*alloccp` is a pointer to the next free position, initially the first (i.e. 0th) element of `allocbuf`. `*alloc` returns a pointer to the first spot in `allocbuf` where the program will be storing the `n` characters.

This can be readily converted to other datatypes, it demonstrates a principle of possible simple allocator design. Clarify your requirements and I can add content.

Comment: That's apparently a homework question. You don't really help OP by showing some different, unrelated code.

Comment: @Olaf: It's not as different and unrelated - it shows a basic memory allocator that can then be modified and extended. The OP did not explain his needs that well - I encouraged him to do so. He was also asking if he needs pointers for the task and this shows just that. I would add a simple usage example but I thought I'll wait for the feedback. I can also solve the OPs issue, but I wasn't sure if that's constructive. If you disagree, I'll extend this answer.

Comment: Read [ask]. If y question does not follow the rules, requuest clarification in a comment. If nothing follows, just don't answer. We are not a coding nor a debugging service. Such answers just encourage bad questions from lazy students who seek someone to do their homework. Designing and debugging/testing are a major part of programming! Actually they take much more time than writing the code.

Comment: @Olaf I agree, thanks for the link. I just thought it was a good idea to post this piece and cite K&R - in an attempt to promote work and understanding :) Technically if OP works through it he'll answer his question for sure and also learn some important things. I definitely didn't want to solve the problem completely though I was tempted. Won't happen next time. True for designing and debugging.

Comment: K&R is not standard and outdated since >18 years now for rev.2 (>28 years for rev. 1). If you want to cite anything, cite the standard (there is only one!) or a reliable interpretation thereof.

Comment: I wasn't asking for the solution to my question to be handed to me and @atru link helped point me in the right direction of what I'm supposed to be doing. Even though I still haven't figured it yet completely, as least now I know I'm completely off track. I'm new to C programming and all I needed was just for someone to let me know if I was on the right track or not. That's all. Thanks

Comment: Glad to help. I learned general programming from this book and, among others, this allocator. Feel free to let me know how it progresses.